# Assign roles to devise user on registration with Rolify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

am working on a system that requires an admin and a normal user,am trying to implement the system using devise,rolify and cancancan.My problem is i want to add an admin role to the first user that signs up on the system, but so far i can only make that happen through the rails console,i did an override of the registrations controller too. below is what i have tried so far.

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
resourcify
rolify
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

role.rb

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord

has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles

belongs_to :resource,
       :polymorphic => true,
       :optional => true

validates :resource_type,
      :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types },
      :allow_nil => true

scopify
end
```

Registrations Controller

```
   class RegistrationsController <   Devise::RegistrationsController

   def create
   super
   @number_of_users = User.all.count
    if @number_of_users == 0
    resource.add_role :admin
  end
  end


  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work,for those who might face such issue in the future,here is my solution

Registration controller

```
   after_action :assign_role, only:[:create]
    def assign_role
      @number_of_users = User.all.count
      if @number_of_users == 1 
        current_user.add_role :admin
     end
    end
```

Comment: Rather than trying to override registrations controller, the above code can be added to applications controller.

Answer (score 0):

I like the accepted solution, but to keep things organized I would put it in the user model like this:

```
after_create :assign_role
def assign_role
  if User.all.count == 1 
    User.first.add_role :admin
  end
end
```